# how to factor out common code when metaclass is used

Tags: python, metaclass

I want to use metaclass to implement a factory which make processors for data coming in from different sources. Following is the skeleton code:

```
class ProcessorFactory

    def __call__(self, classname, supers, classdict):
         ...

    def __New__(self, classname, supers, classdict):
         ...

    def __int__(self):
         ...

class MQ_AddOn(object):
    # MQ-specific code

class File_AddOn(object):
    # Filesystem-specific code

class Web_AddOn(object):
    # Web-specific code

class MQ_Processor(MQ_AddOn, metaclass=ProcessorFactory()):

    # code common to all channels (MQ, Filesystem, Web)

class File_Processor(File_AddOn, metaclass=ProcessorFactory()):

    # code common to all channels (MQ, Filesystem, Web)

class Web_Processor(Web_AddOn, metaclass=ProcessorFactory()):

    # code common to all channels (MQ, Filesystem, Web)
```

My question is whether there is a way, similar to macro expansion in assembly, to factor out the code common to all channels (MQ, Filesystem, Web) so that it doesn't have to be copied for each of those class?

Comment: What is `SorrogateFactory`? Unless it's a callable that returns a metaclass, you want `metaclass=SorrogateFactory`.

Comment: I'm guessing you meant `metaclass=ProcessorFactory` and also it seems you confused the parents: `class File_processor(File_AddOn...)`

Comment: yeah. that was a typo. it's ProcessorFactory. Fixed it.

Comment: I'm a bit confused about what common code you're looking to factor out. Is it just the metaclass part of the `class` statement? I'm further confused about the metaclass being an instance of `ProcessorFactory`, rather than a subclass of `type` (which I don't think is legal). This seems like it may be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/223254).

Answer (score 0):

Sorry - I think you have to expand somewhat more on your pseudocode for a signficative answer.

the way for not copying code around is just use the normal inheritance mechanisms in Python - If you have code common to all those classes, just put that code in a common baseclass, which might be a mixin (i.e. no need for it to be the "only" baseclass), and your are set.

If the common code have to call methods for data aquisition or processing that is specific for each of the subclasses, just write fine grained methods to perform that, and place calls for those in the common method.

Also, there is no need in this process to have ither a "metaclass" or for an "inline macro expansion" - just use plain methods and finer-grained methods.

```py
class Base:
    def process(self,...):
         # preparing code
         ...
         # data gather
         data = self.fetch_data()
         # common data pre-processing code:
         ...
         # specific data processing code:
         post_data = self.refine_data(data)
         # more common code
         ...
         # specific output:
         self.output(post_data)

    def fetch_data(self, ...):
        pass
    def refine_data(self, data):
        pass
    def output(self, data):
        pass
```

And then, on the subclasses you implement those addressing the specific channel peculiarities. There is no big secret there.

Even if you need a lot more things to be done, like steps that are to be called from more than one "leaf" class in each step, you are better of having your class feature a "pipeline" data member, were the steps are annotated and called in order - still, no need to (and no sense in) involving metaclasses.

In your example, the "Base" class could fit all the "common code" you mention, and be used with multiple inheritance:

```py
class MQProcessor(MQAddOn, Base):
   ...

...
```

(when you write `__call__` and `__new__` methods in what would be a metaclass, one might try to think 'ok -these are metaclass-related things that possibly make sense' - but `__int__` in a metaclass makes no sense *at all*: it would provide a way to map a class (not an instance, not some data content) to an integer - even if you are putting these classes in a list, and they need indexes to be located in the list, and you want to cross-reference those, you should just add a custom ".index" attribute to the class, not write `__int__` on the metaclass)